# Sharing our use case and would love to hear if somehow Safe would fit into this

Tags: gnosis-safe

we, at moonbit.ai, are interested in potentially using Safe.

Sharing our use case and would love to hear if you think Safe would fit well.

Current:

- We generate client wallet addresses at our crypto custody provider
- The client can deposits crypto to this wallet and then invest in a crypto portfolio we have created
- Our algorithm then takes the deposited crypto and buys the required cryptos according to the portfolio by connecting with crypto exchanges
- This means clients' cryptos get transferred to an exchange (off-chain) and then get sent back into the client's wallet
- Same logic above when our portfolio rebalances.

Goal:

- Give more ownership to the client
- Move from CeFi to DeFi

Idea:
Clients have a Safe account and clients can give the right to our algorithm to swap (buy/sell) cryptos for the account according to the selected portfolio. Using Web3auth or something would be awesome to onboard web2 and more mainstream clients.

Appreciate your time to share your thoughts on this :).

Comment: I guess it would be better to have this discussion with safe team, or safe specific community.

Comment: Thanks I tried in the Discord group and I was told to try here :)

Comment: Strange....
These things come under partnerships of companies... They should assist with whatever needed.

Comment: @ZartajAfser You are right the advice to ask here is weird. 
I forwarded the question to the business development department at Safe{Wallet}

Comment: That's great @DirkJäckel

Comment: Appreciate it thanks :)